# Struts2 jasperreports - passing export parameters

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

I'm using the struts2 jasperreports plugin and it works well. The problem is that I want to pass exportParameters and I'm not sure how to do that through the plugin.

Comment: see my updated post that is all you have to do to use those export parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of Struts2 you are using starting with `2.1.2+` it provides the feature to provides `exportParameters`

All you need to add following entry or similar entry in your struts config file inside your action class

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.acme.test.action.JasperAction">
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
      <param name="location">foo.jasper</param>
      <param name="dataSource">mySource</param>
      <param name="exportParameters ">exportParameters </param>
    </result>
</action>
```

`exportParameters -  OGNL expression used to retrieve a map of JR exporter parameters from the value stack`. The export parameters are used to customize the JR export. For example, a PDF export might enable encryption and set the user password to a string known to the report creator. 
All you need to define a map for your export parameters in your action class and provides its getter/setter than use its reference as described.

For details refer this URL

[jasperreports](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html)

```
**Update**
```

Here is how they have done it in result type

```
 exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
Map exportParams = (Map) stack.findValue(exportParameters);
             if (exportParams != null) {
                 LOG.debug("Found export parameters; adding to exporter parameters...");
                 exporter.getParameters().putAll(exportParams);
            }
```

so what they did is they tried to find out a `map` in value stack with name `exportParameters` if they find it they are adding it.So have to do this in your action class

```
Map<String,String> exportParameters= //init your map here
```

set your properties in this map and create a getter and setter for this property

```
getExportParameters()
setExportParameters()
```

and in your struts config file declare the map as follows

```
<param name="exportParameters ">exportParameters </param>
```

rest framework will take care
Hope this will help you

Comment: but how to define the exportParameters itself

Comment: what are your export parameters??

Comment: here are the parameters i want to add

Comment: exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);

Comment: You need to set them in your action and in config file do it like <param name="exportParameters">exporter</params> all it need that this "exporter" should be in value stack so that OGNL can fetch it from there

Comment: i am not clear what specific you are asking about can you elaborate?

Comment: well how to put those parameters into a variable and then how to put them in the stack?

Comment: i mean first of all what type should i define the variable exporter then how i put it in the value stack and so on

Comment: thank u very much but would u help me in intializing the map, i know this sounds stupid to you.

Comment: Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>(); now your map is ready and you can put values in it like map.put("key","value");

Comment: i did this and its not working:
 exportParameters.put("JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND", "Boolean.TRUE");