# Struts2 JasperReport plugin exporting to XLS with several Sheets

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, struts2, jasper-reports, xls

I'm using the struts2 jasperreports plugin and it works well. The problem is that I want to pass exportParameters and I'm not sure how to do that through the plugin. I did it:

```
@Result(
   name = "XLS", value = "/<package>/Informe.jasper", 
   type = JasperReportsResult.class, 
   params = {
      "dataSource", "listaResultados", 
      "format", "XLS",      
      "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=\"Informe.xls\"", 
      "exportParameters", "exportParametersJR" 
   }
)

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, String> getExportParametersJR(){
        JRXlsExporter jrXlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        JrXlsExporter.setParameter(
               JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,Boolean.TRUE);
        return jrXlsExporter.getParameters();       
    }
```

I tried, and I got the datasource correctly, but when I add this line

```
"exportParameters", "exportParametersJR"
```

it show me this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult.doExecute(JasperReportsResult.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:178)   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have an Struts version higher or equal to 2.1.2 ? Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254394/struts2-jasperreports-passing-export-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the post that [Andrea Ligios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1654265/andrea-ligios) has commented ([passing parameters to jaspereport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254394/struts2-jasperreports-passing-export-parameters)), I saw that my project is using a old version that not support this feature.

The project uses struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.0.11.1.jar, so the solution was to use iReport 3 for define the property, in this way:

1. add the `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.*` import (edit / Report Import Directives / new Import)
   [image]
2. add the net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet property and set ir to true in the report Custom Properties (edit / Custom Properties / new)
   [image]
3. save
4. compile
5. replace the .jasper file to the project

in this way I got that the project worked like I wanted.